# IIS Flask: /Discovery/HTTPsvc/IISXferWanServer.DLL calling application several times a second

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019, flask

Saw a 404 being generated several times a second, after some debugging I found something is trying to call `/Discovery/HTTPsvc/IISXferWanServer.DLL`

Can you suggest what it is and how I'd go about stopping it?

The remote address seems to be another local server with RealVNC and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on

Thanks

Comment: You're perhaps using the IISxferwanServer Web Extension, probably in the Default Web site in IIS. This seems to be a part of Secure Data Transfer Mechanism (SDTM) or Discovery for Secure Communication.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to disable or remove it? The remote address seems to be another server

Comment: You need to be able to control the IIS server in question.

Comment: Thanks - I've asked IT to look into it. Seems strange.

Comment: Seems there's traffic from 70 different servers! Any idea how to stop this at a firewall level  on the server I'm on?

Comment: Please post a new question for that, with all details.

Comment: Thanks. I'v done. I'm sitting on one of the servers where these requests are coming from and see no reference to this extension... at a loss as to where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a product called Frontrange Solutions from Ivanti that is sitting on some 70+ servers

I have raised this with our internal IT