# IIS/Windows Sever 2019: How to block a request for a specific URL?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

Based on [IIS Flask: /Discovery/HTTPsvc/IISXferWanServer.DLL calling application several times a second](https://superuser.com/questions/1727412/iis-flask-discovery-httpsvc-iisxferwanserver-dll-calling-application-several-t) I was advised to create this question

I have a request for `/Discovery/HTTPsvc/IISXferWanServer.DLL` to my IIS instance on Windows 2019. There are about 600 of these a minute from around 75 servers.

All local network servers.

I have asked IT to look into this but a quick win for me would be to block this URL on my servers that I am working on.

How would I go about doing this? Any examples I could follow?

I'm using Python Flask but I'd rather Flask not take care of it and ideally something before it hits Flask

In IIS, under URL Reqrite, I've added it as a "Add request blocking rule" and that seems to work but was wondering if the firewall itself could stop it

Thanks

Comment: well, there are a number of ways to go about it, but the cleanest would probably be request filtering. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis

Comment: also note, the windows firewall is not a WAF. it will allow or deny traffic based on IP criteria like addresses, transport criteria like ports and protcols, and process criteria like application, but it will not perform application layer filtering based on application protocol data like HTTP request criteria. for that you need an ALG/Proxy/WAF, which do not come built into IIS.